# How to get photo info with photo url on flickr Rest API?

Tags: angular, rest, flickr

I am using below API for getting all info about Flickr image by sending image id but I am not able to get image URL for binding into html and also getting all data in response.

[API Url](http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=2477fc2faa87d31bb3ac9d9929ab6376&photo_id=5340131446&format=json&nojsoncallback=1%22;)

I am getting

---

```
"url": [
                {
                    "type": "photopage",
                    "_content": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/giant_schnauzer/5340131446/"
                }
            ]
```

---

but it's not the image url.

Plaese help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are seeking the information available in the [flickr.photos.getSizes](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html) endpoint.